# Is there a way to hide react-native-maps markers?

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, react-native-maps

I am working on a tourism application, containing a map with markers made using my data.
I want to add the option to "filter" its markers.
The user can press buttons "Restaurants", "Hotels," Commerces" to display only the selected markers.

(The user presses on "Restaurants" -> Show only restaurant markers, here is a picture of the idea :

[image: Map and markers]

Here is the code of my Axios request, nothing big :

```
import axios from 'axios';

// URL API BASE
const APIURL = 'http://10.22.101.55:5000/api';


// RECUPERATION DES RESTAURANTS
export const getAllRestaurant = (nom, adresse, ville, cp, telephone, email, latitude, longitude ) => axios.get(`${APIURL}/restaurant`, {
    nom: nom,
    adresse: adresse,
    ville: ville,
    cp: cp,
    telephone: telephone,
    email: email,
    latitude: latitude,
    longitude: longitude
});

// RECUPERATION DES HôTELS
export const getAllHotel = (nom, adresse, ville, cp, telephone, email, latitude, longitude ) => axios.get(`${APIURL}/hotel`, {
    nom: nom,
    adresse: adresse,
    ville: ville,
    cp: cp,
    telephone: telephone,
    email: email,
    latitude: latitude,
    longitude: longitude
});

// RECUPERATION DES COMMERCES
export const getAllCommerce = (nom, adresse, ville, cp, telephone, email, latitude, longitude ) => axios.get(`${APIURL}/commerce`, {
    nom: nom,
    adresse: adresse,
    ville: ville,
    cp: cp,
    telephone: telephone,
    email: email,
    latitude: latitude,
    longitude: longitude
});
```

And the code of my page, I made sure to separate the different categories hoping that it would be easier :

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, Text} from 'react-native';
import { ScrollView, TextInput } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import MapView, { Marker } from 'react-native-maps';
import Ionicons from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';


// Récupération des données
import {getAllRestaurant, getAllHotel, getAllCommerce} from '../service/Emplacements'

export default function AccueilScreen() {

  // RECUPERATION DES RESTAURANTS
  const [restaurants, setRestaurants] = React.useState([])
  const LesRestaurants = () => [
    getAllRestaurant().then(response => {
      setRestaurants(response.data);
    }).catch(err => console.log(err))
  ]

  // RECUPERATION DES HÔTELS
  const [hotels, setHotels] = React.useState([])
  const LesHotels = () => [
    getAllHotel().then(response => {
      setHotels(response.data);
    }).catch(err => console.log(err))
  ]

  // RECUPERATION DES COMMERCES
  const [commerces, setCommerces] = React.useState([])
  const lesCommerces = () => [
    getAllCommerce().then(response => {
      setCommerces(response.data);
    }).catch(err => console.log(err))
  ]

  // AFFICHAGE DES MARKERS RESTAURANTS
  const afficheRestaurant = restaurants.map((restaurant) => (
    <Marker
      pinColor='#fdca40'
      key={restaurant.id}
      coordinate={{latitude: restaurant.latitude, longitude: restaurant.longitude}}
      title={restaurant.nom}
    />
  )) 

  // AFFICHAGE DES MARKERS HÔTELS
  const afficheHotel = hotels.map((hotel) => (
    <Marker
      pinColor='#2978b5'
      key={hotel.id}
      coordinate={{latitude: hotel.latitude, longitude: hotel.longitude}}
      title={hotel.nom}
    />
  ))

  // AFFICHAGE DES MARKERS COMMERCES
  const afficheCommerce = commerces.map((commerce) => (
    <Marker
      pinColor='#8fd9a8'
      key={commerce.id}
      coordinate={{latitude: commerce.latitude, longitude: commerce.longitude}}
      title={commerce.nom}
    />
  ))

  // FILTRE RESTAURANT
  const onlyRestaurant = () => {
    afficheCommerce = commerces.map((null))
    afficheHotel = hotels.map((null))
  }

  // CHARGEMENT DES EMPLACEMENTS
  useEffect(() => {
    LesRestaurants()
    LesHotels()
    lesCommerces()
  },[])


  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>

      {/* -- MAP ET MARKERS -- */}
      <MapView
        customMapStyle={MapStyle}
        scrollEnabled={false}
        rotateEnabled={false}
        zoomEnabled={false}
        minZoomLevel={0}
        maxZoomLevel={13}
        style={styles.container}
        region={{
          latitude: 49.4826616,
          longitude: 1.7245633,
          latitudeDelta: 0.015,
          longitudeDelta: 0.0121,
        }}
      >
        {afficheRestaurant}

        {afficheHotel}

        {afficheCommerce}

      </MapView>

      {/* -- BARRE RECHERCHE -- */}
      <View style={styles.searchBox}>
        <TextInput
          placeholder='Rechercher un lieu ...'
          placeholderTextColor='#fb3640'
          style={{flex: 1, padding: 0}}
        />
        <Ionicons name='search-outline' size={20}/>
      </View>

      {/* -- FILTRE -- */}
      <ScrollView
        horizontal
        scrollEventThrottle={1}
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
        height={50}
        style={styles.scroll}
        contentContainerStyle={{paddingRight: 20}}
      >

        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.itemAll}>
          <Ionicons size={15} name='options-outline'>  Tout</Ionicons>
        </TouchableOpacity>

        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.itemRestaurant} onPress={onlyRestaurant}>
          <Ionicons size={15} name='restaurant-outline'>  Restaurant</Ionicons>
        </TouchableOpacity>

        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.itemHotel}>
          <Ionicons size={15} name='bed-outline'>  Hôtel</Ionicons>
        </TouchableOpacity>

        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.itemCommerce}>
          <Ionicons size={15} name='cart-outline'>  Commerce</Ionicons>
        </TouchableOpacity>

      </ScrollView>

   </View>
  );
}

// STYLE DE LA PAGE
{...}

 // STYLE DE LA CARTE
 {...}
```

I did some testing (const onylRestaurant) but nothing good (.map can be null, or read-only errors).

I wanted to know if you have any ideas that I can use

Thanks for any help!

Do not hesitate to ask me for additional information, I'm still new to react-native but I will do my best to answer you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right path.

Have another state variable in your Component.

`const [currentCategory, setCurrentCategory] = React.useState('All');`

When the user clicks on any button, update this variable with corresponding category.

Then use this new state variable to decide which markers you want to show. Something like this.

```
const getMarkers = () => {
    switch (currentCategory) {
        case 'hotel': return afficheHotel;
        case 'restaurant': return afficheRestaurant;
        case 'commerce': return afficheCommerce;
        default: return [...afficheHotel, ...afficheRestaurant, ...afficheCommerce];
    }
}
```

Now write a function to update this state variable by handling onClick

```
const onCategoryClick = category => {
    setCurrentCategory(category);
}
```

Now use the above function in your code like this

```
<TouchableOpacity style={styles.itemAll} onPress={() => onCategoryClick('All')}>
      <Ionicons size={15} name='options-outline'>  Tout</Ionicons>
</TouchableOpacity>

<TouchableOpacity style={styles.itemRestaurant} onPress={() => onCategoryClick('restaurant')}>
      <Ionicons size={15} name='restaurant-outline'>  Restaurant</Ionicons>
</TouchableOpacity>

<TouchableOpacity style={styles.itemHotel} onPress={() => onCategoryClick('hotel')}>
      <Ionicons size={15} name='bed-outline'>  Hôtel</Ionicons>
</TouchableOpacity>

<TouchableOpacity style={styles.itemCommerce} onPress={() => onCategoryClick('commerce')}>
      <Ionicons size={15} name='cart-outline'>  Commerce</Ionicons>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Finally, you would have to update your code to remove this part inside your MapView

```
{afficheRestaurant}

{afficheHotel}

{afficheCommerce}
```

and in its place add this

```
{getMarkers()}
```

so your Mapview will be this,

```
<MapView
    customMapStyle={MapStyle}
    scrollEnabled={false}
    rotateEnabled={false}
    zoomEnabled={false}
    minZoomLevel={0}
    maxZoomLevel={13}
    style={styles.container}
    region={{
      latitude: 49.4826616,
      longitude: 1.7245633,
      latitudeDelta: 0.015,
      longitudeDelta: 0.0121,
    }}
  >
    {getMarkers()}
</MapView>
```

Does this work ?

Comment: First of all thank you for your answer, unfortunately it does not seem to work, can you add some clarification on your answer ? Maybe it's me doing it wrong.

Comment: @QuentinBlanche You can update your new code in the question. I can check it.

Comment: Yeah the problem is me, I make this on the onPress = 
onPress={() => setCurrentCategory('restaurant'), getMarkers}
Of course the currentCategory is still at 'All'

Comment: Truly a newbie question but how can I change the state of currentCategory in my onPress action ? It's my only problem because if I set by default currentCategory directly in the component 'GetMarkers' it work just fine.

Comment: @QuentinBlanche I have updated the answer to include most of the code that you have to change. Check it out.

Comment: Oh man, thanks you so much for your anwser, it's just what I needed. Didn't think a second that I need to make a component 'onCategoryClick' ... I was trying to setState of currentCategory in my onPress ... Thanks a lot for your time and your patience !